# How do I specify a css margin-top for foundation row div?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How do I specify a css margin-top for foundation row div?
Using the Chrome dev tools it looks like foundation.css is overriding any margin properties for .row divs - regardless of where I put the css.

In the interest of getting something out the door today I have resorted to inserting my own divs between the rows  - yuk.

Comment: can you provide a code example?

Comment: Without a sample code, the only thing to suggest is to study CSS specificity: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ and test here: http://specificity.keegan.st/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
div.row {
  margin-top: 12px;
}
```

or

```
.row {
  margin-top: 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: Great -thanks for that.  I didn't realise you had to put "div" in front of ".row".  I've now got it working with my class as I had intended:
div.row.menuRow {  margin-top: 30px;}

Comment: No problem. Actually, you don't "have" to put div in front of .row, you just have to use a selector that has "more priority" than the one foundation use(higher specificity). You could accomplish the same thing with many different ways.